# Extra numbers appearing after JSONArray creation

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, arrays

I'm creating a JSONArray with javascript, and something strange happened to my new Array:

```
var arrayfinal = new Array();

//Order array by elements
function SortByPuntuation(x,y) {
   return x.puntuation - y.puntuation; 
}

for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(arrayfinal){
        arrayfinal[i] = arrayfinal.push({'cathegory':data[i].cname , 'puntuation' : 2 * data[i].cnumber + data[i].click});
    }
    else{
        arrayfinal[i] = {'cathegory':data[i].cname , 'puntuation' : 2 * data[i].cnumber + data[i].click };
    }
};

arrayfinal = arrayfinal.sort(SortByPuntuation);
```

The data is another array:

```
{"cname":"Sillas","cnumber":0,"click":1},
{"cname":"Mesas","cnumber":0,"click":2},
{"cname":"Plastico diferente","cnumber":0,"click":0},
{"cname":"Vasos","cnumber":5,"click":7},
{"cname":"Ordenadores","cnumber":0,"click":2},
{"cname":"Envases cuadrados","cnumber":0,"click":0},
{"cname":"Envases redondos","cnumber":0,"click":0},
{"cname":"Teclados ordenador","cnumber":0,"click":0},
{"cname":"Film transparente","cnumber":0,"click":0},
{"cname":"Pantallas","cnumber":0,"click":1},
{"cname":"Papeles","cnumber":0,"click":2},
{"cname":"Otro","cnumber":0,"click":0},
{"cname":"Coches","cnumber":0,"click":9},
{"cname":"Libros","cnumber":0,"click":2},
{"cname":"Asus","cnumber":0,"click":1}
```

And the finalarray result is:

```
[ 29,
  { cathegory: 'Plastico diferente', puntuation: 0 },
  { cathegory: 'Envases cuadrados', puntuation: 0 },
  { cathegory: 'Otro', puntuation: 0 },
  { cathegory: 'Envases redondos', puntuation: 0 },
  { cathegory: 'Film transparente', puntuation: 0 },
  { cathegory: 'Teclados ordenador', puntuation: 0 },
  22,
  21,
  20,
  19,
  18,
  17,
  16,
  28,
  { cathegory: 'Sillas', puntuation: 1 },
  27,
  26,
  25,
  { cathegory: 'Pantallas', puntuation: 1 },
  24,
  23,
  { cathegory: 'Papeles', puntuation: 2 },
  { cathegory: 'Ordenadores', puntuation: 2 },
  { cathegory: 'Libros', puntuation: 2 },
  { cathegory: 'Mesas', puntuation: 2 },
  { cathegory: 'Coches', puntuation: 9 },
  { cathegory: 'Vasos', puntuation: 17 },
  1 ]
```

Where do the numbers that appear in the finalarray come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're assigning the result of the `push` (which is the new length) to `arrayfinal[i]`.

Change

```
arrayfinal[i] = arrayfinal.push({'cathegory':data[i].cname , 'puntuation' : 2 * data[i].cnumber + data[i].click});
```

to

```
arrayfinal.push({'cathegory':data[i].cname , 'puntuation' : 2 * data[i].cnumber + data[i].click});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code could normally work by initializing the array, using a forward loop and pushing each element to the array.

```
var arrayfinal = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    arrayfinal.push({
      'cathegory':data[i].cname ,
      'puntuation' : 2 * data[i].cnumber + data[i].click
    });
};
```

Avoiding the problem you created by mixing up array look up and [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
arrayfinal[i] = arrayfinal.push(...);
```

which returns the new length of the array after the element is added to it.

---

Alternatively, you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var arrayfinal = data.map(function(category){
  return {
    'cathegory': category.cname,
    'puntuation': 2 * category.cnumber + category.click
  };
});
```